# Where can I get a lifecycle-action-token for aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

```
aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action --lifecycle-action-token ???????? --lifecycle-hook-name ReadyForSoftwareInstall --auto-scaling-group-name  --lifecycle-action-result CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifecycle-action-token is provided by Auto Scaling in the message sent as part of processing the lifecycle hook. You need to get the token from the original message.

If this is a CodeDeploy hook in your Auto Scaling Group, that message goes to CodeDeploy. You can't manually close the Auto Scaling lifecycle action in that case.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can avoid to use the token and use the instance_id:

```
aws autoscaling complete-lifecycle-action --auto-scaling-group-name my_service  --lifecycle-hook-name my_lifecycle_hook --instance-id my_instance_id --lifecycle-action-result CONTINUE
```

Comment: I am getting this error: `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CompleteLifecycleAction operation: No active Lifecycle Action found with instance ID i-XXXXXXXXXXX`

Comment: yeah.. it's updated... after observing the ASG closely, i found that the ASG performs lifecycle action on the particular instance, after which the token is invalid. So the command seems to be working.

Comment: @VarunChandak, How did you resolve the issue `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CompleteLifecycleAction operation: No active Lifecycle Action found with instance ID i-XXXXXXXXXXX. ` Can you provide me with any reference?

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar could be that instance is no longer part of ASG

Answer (score 0):

It's an optional parameter, you don't have to send it if you haven't stored it.